# Removing the Parent Node in XML when the Child element is Empty using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I am facing an issue while using XSLT to transform the file to delete the parent node if the child element is empty. I tried to use different values but they all leave the output as is. Can anyone please let me know the way to handle this.

XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:getDocumentByKeyResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
     <Document xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
        <Attributes>
           <Attribute name="count">89</Attribute>
           <Attribute name="duration">0:00:00.088</Attribute>
           <Attribute name="entity">Candidate</Attribute>
           <Attribute name="mode">XML</Attribute>
           <Attribute name="version">http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01</Attribute>
        </Attributes>
        <Content>
           <ExportXML>
              <record>
                 <field name="Identifier">2341905</field>
                 <field name="CandidateNumber">2341905</field>
                 <field name="RequisitionNumber">AUS053476</field>
                 <field name="Sequence" />
                 <field name="EmploymentCheckDue">Pre-start date,Requested,28. Directorship,2016-07-29</field>
              </record>
              <record>
                 <field name="Identifier">2341905</field>
                 <field name="CandidateNumber">2341905</field>
                 <field name="RequisitionNumber">AUS053476</field>
                 <field name="Sequence" />
                 <field name="EmploymentCheckDue">Pre-start date,Requested,28. Directorship,2016-07-29</field>
              </record>
              <record>
                 <field name="Identifier">2341905</field>
                 <field name="CandidateNumber">2341905</field>
                 <field name="RequisitionNumber">AUS053476</field>
                 <field name="Sequence" />
                 <field name="EmploymentCheckDue">Pre-start date,Requested,26. Dodd-Frank Check,2016-07-29</field>
              </record>
              <record>
                 <field name="Identifier">2341905</field>
                 <field name="CandidateNumber">2341905</field>
                 <field name="RequisitionNumber">AUS053476</field>
                 <field name="Sequence" />
                 <field name="EmploymentCheckDue">Pre-start date,Requested,22. Credit / Bankruptcy / ASIC / APRA,2016-07-29</field>
              </record>
              <record>
                 <field name="Identifier">2341905</field>
                 <field name="CandidateNumber">2341905</field>
                 <field name="RequisitionNumber">AUS053476</field>
                 <field name="Sequence" />
                 <field name="EmploymentCheckDue" />
              </record>
              <record>
                 <field name="Identifier">2341905</field>
                 <field name="CandidateNumber">2341905</field>
                 <field name="RequisitionNumber">AUS053476</field>
                 <field name="Sequence" />
                 <field name="EmploymentCheckDue">Pre-start date,Requested,16. Education / professional,2016-07-29</field>
              </record>
              <record>
                 <field name="Identifier">2341905</field>
                 <field name="CandidateNumber">2341905</field>
                 <field name="RequisitionNumber">AUS053476</field>
                 <field name="Sequence" />
                 <field name="EmploymentCheckDue" />
              </record>
              <record>
                 <field name="Identifier">2341905</field>
                 <field name="CandidateNumber">2341905</field>
                 <field name="RequisitionNumber">AUS053476</field>
                 <field name="Sequence" />
                 <field name="EmploymentCheckDue" />
              </record>
           </ExportXML>
        </Content>
     </Document>
  </ns1:getDocumentByKeyResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="record[not(field = '')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The element you're trying to match is in a default namespace (http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07). Bind the namespace to a prefix in your stylesheet and use it in your xpath. If you need examples, search for xpath default namespace and you'll have plenty.

Comment: In addition to the namespace issue, your requirement is not clear. Which record/s in the given example should be removed? Note that your template would remove any record that does **not** have at least one empty field.